# Preparing for steam boiler maintenance

Tags: boiler, radiator, maintenance

I've just moved into a new house with radiator heat/steam boiler, and there seem to be a few issues (loud banging noises on startup, one radiator leaking). I have a maintenance person coming out next week to flush the system, but I just wanted to check on things I might do in advance to save me money before they come. Do the following steps seem sensible?

1. One or two of the radiators are "leaning" in the wrong direction (they slope down "away" from the pipe rather than slope towards the pipe). I thought I would buy a few wooden blocks to prop those up. I thought I read somewhere that a 5 degree angle is ideal, is this right?
2. By some replacement valves if this is easy to do? (One radiator seems to be missing the shut off valve).
3. A few hours before the maintenance person arrives, turn off the boiler so it is cool and so can be drained without waiting.

Do these make sense and is there anything I'm missing? At the hourly rate I'm paying, I want to make sure I'm getting expert plumbing rather than someone waiting for pipes to cool down or going to home depot to buy a piece of wood.

Comment: Consult with the maintenance person regarding shutting off the boiler - if they want that, they'll tell you, normally, but for sure ask them before just doing it.

Comment: I only got to schedule the appointment with a secretary so I'm not sure I will get a chance to speak to anyone before they arrive.

Comment: You may end up paying for someone to wait for it to warm up and reproduce the issue. If you make changes prior to diagnosis, it might not save you anything. IMO, I’d have stuff like wooden shims you might need, but other than that I’d let the technician check it’s function as is. For prep I make sure they have space, lighting, and access to power if I think they’ll need it.